# How to configure Dropbox as a service

Tags: windows-home-server, dropbox

I'm a happy user of Dropbox, but I want to use it with my Windows Home Server.

I would like to ask if it's possible to run it as a service. The default installation installs dropbox.exe in C:\Documents and Settings\administrator\Application Data\Dropbox\bin

That path prevents me from creating a user-defined service using Windows Resource Kits.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found a forum post (now deleted) which describes a solution for Windows Home Server. There is also another post that covers [Running Dropbox as a service on Windows Server 2008](http://blog.jayway.com/2011/07/12/running-dropbox-as-a-service-on-windows-server-2008/). The description below is for WHS.

First, run the Dropbox installer using the [command line switch](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=15219) `/D=C:\Program Files\Dropbox` (with no quotes) to install Dropbox into the Program Files directory for all users.

Then here an updated version of the procedure given on this link:

> Since [Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com/) will normally only work
>   when a user is logged in, we will have
>   to install and use it first via remote
>   desktop, before it can be turned it
>   into a Service.
>
> 1. Remote desktop to your WHS as administrator
> 2. Get DropBox from their website.
> 3. Install and configure Dropbox as you like. e.g. I made a special share on my WHS named Dropbox before the installation and linked Dropbox to this share. Then exit dropbox from the system tray.
> 4. Similar to Foldershare, you will need instsrv.exe and srvany.exe from the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en) Tools.
> 5. Copy instsrv.exe to `C:\Program Files\Dropbox`
> 6. Copy srvany.exe to `C:\Program Files\Dropbox`
> 7. execute `"C:\Program Files\Dropbox\instsrv.exe" Dropbox "C:\Program Files\Dropbox\srvany.exe"`
> 8. execute `reg ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dropbox\Parameters /v Application /d "C:\Program Files\Dropbox\Dropbox.exe"`
> 9. execute `reg ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dropbox\Parameters /v AppDirectory /d "C:\Program Files\Dropbox"`
> 10. Delete or move the shorcut to Dropbox away from the startfolder (Start -> All Programs -> Startup) on the startmenu.
> 11. Move (cut/paste) ALL the files from `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\DropBox` to `C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\Application Data\Dropbox`
> 12. execute `net start Dropbox`

Comment: One step to add: As Dropbox installs into Application data, you need to create the folder c:\program files\dropbox and copy all files from the Dropbox\bin directory to it

Comment: Is there a similar version for Windows Server 2008?

Comment: I managed to get this working (Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit) using this article http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverMigration/thread/98a97aee-c62b-4683-94ab-3777899cf7de/ - I didn't need to use instsrv.exe - just srvany.exe pointing to Dropbox

Comment: I use TaskScheduler and start Dropbox when system start. Work like a charm. :)

Comment: note: srvany.exe HAS to be in the same dir as dropbox.exe, instsrv can be anywhere on the path

Comment: Added a link to [Running Dropbox as a service on Windows Server 2008](http://blog.jayway.com/2011/07/12/running-dropbox-as-a-service-on-windows-server-2008/).

Answer (score 0):

[Any2Service](http://www.fryshell.com/index-1.html#Any2Service__v1.1.5) supposedly lets you turn any exe into a service. Haven't been using it in a long time myself but maybe it's worth a try.

Comment: Link is broken.